# an effective way to merge over 10 files having more than million lines each on a column

Tags: python, memory, merge

I need to merge 83 files on their first column, and the ids in the 1st column is not always the same across the files. As these files contain more than a few million lines each, I need a computationally effective way to merge them in a wide format.

So I slightly modified the python answer in [this question by Stephen Rauch](https://superuser.com/questions/1245094/merging-multiple-files-based-on-the-common-column). Which is reading each file one by one in directory with the right pattern, creating a dictionary with sampleID containing id-value matches, then calling each id as a row from all the dictionaries.

```
from os import listdir
import fnmatch
import re


vcfs= fnmatch.filter(listdir("."), "pivotted_vaf_out*")

columns = []
data = {}
ids = set()

for filename in vcfs:
    with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
        key=re.findall(r"[0-9]+",filename)[0]
        columns.append(key)
        data[key] = {}
        for line in f:
            if line.strip():
                id, value = line.strip().split()
                try:
                    data[key][(id)] = value
                except ValueError as exc:
                    raise ValueError(
                        "Problem in line: '{}' '{}' '{}'".format(
                            id, value, line.rstrip()))

                ids.add((id))

print('\t'.join(['ID'] + columns))

for id in sorted(ids):
    line = []
    for column in columns:
        line.append(data[column].get(id, './.'))
    print('\t'.join([str(id)] + line))
```

My input and output looks like the following.

```
File1.tsv
chr1_13868_A_G  0/1
chr1_13896_C_A  0/1
chr1_14464_A_T  1/1
chr1_14653_C_T  0/1

File2.tsv
chr1_13868_A_G  0/1
chr1_14464_A_T  1/1
chr1_14654_G_T  1/1

File3.tsv
chr1_13868_A_G  0/1
chr1_13896_C_A  0/1
chr1_14464_A_T  1/1
chr1_14653_C_T  0/1

Together.tsv
ID     1     2     3
chr1_13868_A_G  0/1     0/1     0/1
chr1_13896_C_A  0/1     ./.     0/1
chr1_14464_A_T  1/1     1/1     1/1
chr1_14653_C_T  0/1     0/1     0/1
chr1_14654_G_T  1/1     ./.     ./.
```

This code works perfectly, if I allocate a good amount of memory. I am wondering what alternative and effective solutions are there for joining/mergin a large amount of files with large number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tools already available in POSIX: `sort` and `join`. Python is generally wasteful about memory (object overhead), and you'd likely need to write code, when it's all already done for you in POSIX tools. (I don't know if a ready-made thing exists.)

Furthermore, POSIX `join` will not need files in memory to do its magic (it only reads one line at a time from each file), and sorting can be done serially (so you only need one file in memory at a time).

Sort each file individually:

```
sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 File1.tsv > File1.sorted.tsv
sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 File2.tsv > File2.sorted.tsv
sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 File3.tsv > File3.sorted.tsv
```

then join them one by one:

```
join -t$'\t' -a1 -a2 -e./. -o0,1.2,2.2 File1.sorted.tsv File2.sorted.tsv > join_2.tsv
join -t$'\t' -a1 -a2 -e./. -o0,1.2,1.3,2.2 join_2.tsv File3.sorted.tsv > join_3.tsv
```

Unfortunately, you will need to list all the fields in `join` (I don't know a way around it); you need `-o0,` followed by `1.x` for each data column in the first of the files you're joining, starting with 2 (i.e. `join_2.tsv` has two data columns, so you need `1.2,1.3`) followed by `2.2`. By the 83rd file, the `-o` list will have to get pretty fat. :(

Obviously, it would be awesome to either write a loop (perfectly possible in bash, though a bit messy), or to write a program to generate all 165 commands you will need. You do *not* want to do this by hand :D

Anyway, explanation of the syntax: `join` requires that the files be sorted, and the sorting order must be the same as the one `join` is using. Thus, `-t` option (for both `sort` and `join`) establish tab as the delimiter, and `-k1,1` option makes sure `sort` only considers the join column, and not join column as a *primary* sort criterion (disambiguating ties with other columns) as it would by default. `-a1 -a2` is producing a full outer join, and `-e./.` is specifying `./.` should be used for nulls. Finally, `join` will not output any null fields (even though we specified `-e`) unless you list the output fields with `-o` (sheesh).